# React-admin: getting error with nested item

Tags: react-admin

When I create an Input like:

The rendering is ok, but when submiting I get the error:
index.js:1446 Warning: Missing translation for key: "Cannot read property 'name' of null"

```
export const PatientCreate = props => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <NumberInput source="bsn" />
      <TextInput source="patientname.firstname" />
      <BooleanInput source="active" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);
```

When I remove the nested item patientname.firstname, everythings works correctlty..Anyone idea ?

Using Prisma server data, but the error is in Create, before a put is happening, so I think I has something to do with react-admin..
Model is (Prisma MongoDB):

```
type Patient {
  id: ID! @id
  bsn: Int @unique
  active: Boolean! @default(value: true)
  patientname: Patientname
  deceased: DateTime
}

type Patientname @embedded {
  firstname: String
}
```

In React-admin documentaion:
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#textinput

```
<TextInput source="author.firstName" />
```

Tnx I anyone can help me ...

Paul

Comment: Hi, thanks for reporting this. Mind you writing the full error stacktrace? Also, it would be great if you can reproduce the error on this CodeSandbox and then share the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5q09v99xl

Comment: I would suggest you to also provide the code for the data provider.

Answer (score 0):

In your i18n translation files need to respect the nested reference.

React admin tries to translate using property `resources.[resourcename].fields.[fieldname] ([see docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#translating-resource-and-field-names)) if none is present it uses the string on source prop. If you have nested resources and no translation file with nested reference that error will be presented because can't find nested source.

If you create a translation file like this:

```js
const language = {
  resources: {
    patient: {
      patientname: {
        firstname: "firstname"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Your problem is fixed. Take note that you need to add this translation resource to react-admin, more information can be found [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers !

After a little digging into the details, the message comes from the i18n translation. It is coming fromthe fact the the nested item is returned null, so the is no object patientname at all..

I'm using the ra-admin-prisma [link](https://github.com/Weakky/ra-data-opencrud) dataprovider, but the nested item handler, based on "mongodb" embedded item is not working correctly (alreadu an issue on github..

Thanks a lot, now the i18n translation, with resource translation is working correctly!